# Failed to install dependencies

Tags: apt, server, package-management

Hello I have to repair a series of packages on an ubuntu server when I run the command: **apt-get install -f** . As required in the comments I added the logs of the **apt-get update** command and the grep of the **source.list**. 
The error is due to the fact that on this server it has been "managed" by several people who have done a little what they wanted, now they ask me to fix it but I don't really know where to start I tried to clean up the locks perform an fsck and everything that could come to mind but I don't know how to fix it can you explain how to do it?

> apt-get install -f

I have the following list of errors, how can I solve them?

**Version:**

```
No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:   
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Release:        18.04 Codename:       bionic
```

**Error:**

```
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:62 and /etc/apt/sources.list:67
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6:amd64:
 libstdc++6:amd64 depends on gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1); however:
  Version of gcc-5-base:amd64 on system is 5.5.0-12ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++6:amd64
 apt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-utils : Depends: apt (= 1.6.3) but 1.4.9 is installed
 libcephfs2 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1 is installed
 libclang1-6.0 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1 is installed
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not installed
 libgnutls30 : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not installed
 libhogweed4 : Depends: libnettle6 (= 3.4-1) but it is not installed
 libidn2-dev : Depends: libidn2-0 (= 2.2.0-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.0.4-1.1build2 is installed
 libllvm6.0 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1 is installed
 librados2 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1 is installed
 librtmp1 : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not installed
 libstdc++-5-dev : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1) but 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1 is installed
 libstdc++-7-dev : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) but 5.5.0-12ubuntu1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

**sources.list**

```
 /etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3)]/ trusty main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3)]/ trusty main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib # disabled on upgrade to xenial
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable main non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ee.list:deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ee.list:deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list.save:# deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list:deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial edge
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/zabbix.list.distUpgrade:deb http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/zabbix.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-17_03-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-17_03-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list.save:deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list.save:deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list:deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list:# deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list.distUpgrade:deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-17_03-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-17_03-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnishcache_varnish5.list.save:deb https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnishcache_varnish5.list.save:deb-src https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list:deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list:deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openproject-ce.list.save:deb https://dl.packager.io/srvdeb/opf/openproject-ce/stable/7/ubuntu 16.04 main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-17_03-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-17_03-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/17.03/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list.dpkg-old:deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb ./public main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list.save:deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list.distUpgrade:# deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openproject-ce.list:deb https://dl.packager.io/srv/deb/opf/openproject-ce/stable/7/ubuntu 16.04 main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ee.list.save:deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ee.list.save:deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list.save:deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list.save:deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/zabbix.list:deb http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/zabbix.list:deb-src http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list.save:deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/zabbix.list.save:deb http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/zabbix.list.save:deb-src http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list.save:deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list.save:deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial edge
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/100-ubnt-unifi.list.save:deb http://www.ubnt.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable ubiquiti
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list.distUpgrade:deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list.distUpgrade:deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openproject-ce.list.distUpgrade:deb https://dl.packager.io/srv/deb/opf/openproject-ce/stable/7/ubuntu 16.04 main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list.save:deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/100-ubnt-unifi.list.distUpgrade:deb http://www.ubnt.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable ubiquiti
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list:deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list.distUpgrade:deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list.save:deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list.distUpgrade:deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnishcache_varnish5.list:deb https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnishcache_varnish5.list:deb-src https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnishcache_varnish5.list.distUpgrade:deb https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnishcache_varnish5.list.distUpgrade:deb-src https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list:deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list:deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/100-ubnt-unifi.list:deb http://www.ubnt.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable ubiquiti
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list:deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3)]/ trusty main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3)]/ trusty main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib # disabled on upgrade to xenial
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3)]/ trusty main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3)]/ trusty main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib # disabled on upgrade to xenial
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable main non-free
```

**output of apt-get update:**
https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/9b522ed9e6c4d25709c31e55b96e2cbd

Comment: Also show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: @nobody i have add it

Comment: @user535733 i have add output of command on gist: https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/9b522ed9e6c4d25709c31e55b96e2cbd

Comment: Egad, those outputs are utterly horrifying: Ignored warnings, at least three different releases mixed together, vast numbers of PPAs and third-party repositories. How skilled are you at package management? Do you understand how package sources work with apt? Is there anything mission-critical running on this machine? Is there an established set of priorities for what to repair first? Depending upon what you have running on this server, and upon your skill set, reinstall may be easier -- has reinstall been considered as a solution? Either way, this is going to be a big job.

Comment: Upps, save your data and install new. @user535733 is right. There would be much  to do.